# How to convert WAV audio files for Core Audio playback?

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, openal

I'm using Core Audio / OpenAL to play CAF audio files. From Apple I know that the best file format is this:

**Core Audio File Format (CAFF), mono, 16-bit @ 44,1 kHz**

So I launched Soundtrack Pro 3 and saved an WAV file as an "Core Audio File" with 44,1 kH, 16-bit integer.

When I play it back, it is strongly distorted and has a horrible quality. When I play it back on the mac hitting spacebar (quicklook), the sound is perfectly fine.

What must I do that I can play my own sound files in Core Audio? Is there a special tool from Apple that would convert the sound files in such a way that they're instantly playable with Core Audio?

Comment: Core Audio can play most popular formats.  Can you post some code?

Comment: *the best file format is this: Core Audio File Format (CAFF), mono, 16-bit @ 44,1 kHz* -- there's no reason that would be superior to 16 bit LPCM WAV. anyways… maybe STP had an endian mismatch? the error would be HUGE if that were the case -- hardly distinguishable in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple documentation:

```
 afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 something.m4a something.caf
```

Comment: You must enter this command in Terminal (do a quicklook search for it on your Mac). Drag the file you want to convert in there to get the full path. Then drag again and change the extension.